# jquery/javascript check string for multiple substrings

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, search

I need to check if a string has one of three substrings, and if yes, to implement a function. I know I can check for one substring using `if (str.indexOf("term1") >= 0)` but is there a way to check for multiple substrings short of using several instances of this code?

TIA

Comment: `if (str.indexOf("term1") >= 0 || str.indexOf("term2") >= 0 || str.indexOf("term3") >= 0)` How difficult could it be?

Answer (score 33):

```
if (/term1|term2|term3/.test("your string")) {
   //youre code
}
```

Comment: You don't have to explain downvotes but I'd guess that not everyone likes Regexes. In this situation they aren't needed and some may say they make the code less readable.

Comment: Buth they're simple and elegant. Why would I want to use loong OR (||) clause or loops If I know my regex.

Comment: explanation of the answer is missing why would you ask for explanation of downvote?Dont ask for something you didnt give.

Comment: Great answer! Worked for me and helped me find a slightly easier-to-follow version that also worked:  str = "your string"; str.match(/(term1|term2|term3)/g);   but match is technically inferior in this case of course

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346171/js-regex-to-find-multiple-substrings-in-string was the alternative form

Answer (score 28):

This achieves dynamically and elegantly what you are trying to do

```
const terms = ["term1", "term2", "term3"]
const str = "very large string to check for term1, tern2, etc ..."

// check if the string has some of the terms
const result1 = terms.some(term => str.includes(term))

// check if the string has all the terms
const result2 = terms.every(term => str.includes(term))
```

This also makes it easy to filter an array of strings for an array of substrings

```
const terms = ["term1", "term2", "term3"]
const strings = ["very large string text ....", "another large string text"] 

// filter the strings of the array that contain some of the substrings we're looking for
const result1 = strings.filter(str => terms.some(term => str.includes(term)))

// filter the strings of the array that contain all the substrings we're looking for
const result2 = strings.filter(str => terms.every(term => str.includes(term)))
```

Comment: this is a great solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a loop. Maybe even create a helper function like so:

```
function ContainsAny(str, items){
    for(var i in items){
        var item = items[i];
        if (str.indexOf(item) > -1){
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Which you can then call like so:

```
if(ContainsAny(str, ["term1", "term2", "term3"])){
   //do something
}
```

Comment: From the question: "I need to check if a string has **one of three** substrings" It's not a requirement for *all* of them to be present, only at least one of them.

Answer (score 4):

The `.map()` function can be used to convert an array of terms into an array of **booleans** indicating if each term is found.  Then check if any of the **booleans** are `true`.

Given an array of `terms`:

```
const terms = ['term1', 'term2', 'term3'];
```

This line of code will return `true` if `string` contains any of the `terms`:

```
terms.map((term) => string.includes(term)).includes(true);
```

Three examples:

```
terms.map((term) => 'Got term2 here'.includes(term)).includes(true);       //true
terms.map((term) => 'Not here'.includes(term)).includes(true);             //false
terms.map((term) => 'Got term1 and term3'.includes(term)).includes(true);  //true
```

Or, if you want to wrap the code up into a reusable `hasTerm()` function:

```
const hasTerm = (string, terms) =>
   terms.map(term => string.includes(term)).includes(true);

hasTerm('Got term2 here', terms);       //true
hasTerm('Not here', terms);             //false
hasTerm('Got term1 and term3', terms);  //true
```

Try it out:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MzKZZQ?editors=0012

`.map()` documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

**Note:**
This answer optimizes for simplicity and readability.  If extremely large arrays of terms are expected, use a loop that short-circuits once a term is found.

Comment: That's o(n) which is kinda slow

Comment: Sorry @Rongeegee but your blanket statement is wrong because you failed to optimized for the developer.  The bold note clearly explains the optimization criteria and even mentions an alternate strategy depending on what needs optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this:

```
if (str.indexOf("term1") >= 0 || str.indexOf("term2") >= 0 || str.indexOf("term3") >= 0) 
{
 //your code
}
```

Comment: Not ideal for an unknown number of terms though

Comment: I agree, but he asked for 3 substrings.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
function isSubStringPresent(str){
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        if(str.indexOf(arguments[i]) > -1){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

isSubStringPresent('mystring', 'term1', 'term2', ...)
```

Comment: Never seen this before, using extra arguments. Can you point me to the docs?

Comment: Interesting, I never knew about `arguments` before... though I assume this will be vulnerable to redefinition?

Comment: every javascript method get a hidden parameter called `arguments` which is an array like structure with all the parameters passed to the method. It is like variable arguments in java

Comment: On the other hand, isn't you snippet wrong? You will exit with false if any of the substrings are not in the string. Doesn't the OP want to check that at least one is in the string?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko missed it, i thought it was all three, made the changes

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to check for multiple string matches and highlight them, this code snippet works.**

```
function highlightMatch(text, matchString) {
    let textArr = text.split(' ');
    let returnArr = [];
    
    for(let i=0; i<textArr.length; i++) {
        let subStrMatch = textArr[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(matchString.toLowerCase());
        
        if(subStrMatch !== -1) {
            let subStr = textArr[i].split('');
            let subStrReturn = [];
            
            for(let j=0 ;j<subStr.length; j++) {
                
                if(j === subStrMatch) {
                    subStrReturn.push('<strong>' + subStr[j]);    
                } else if (j === subStrMatch + (matchString.length-1)){
                    subStrReturn.push(subStr[j] + '<strong>');
                } else {
                    subStrReturn.push(subStr[j]);
                }
            }
            returnArr.push(subStrReturn.join(''));
        } else {
            returnArr.push(textArr[i]);
        }
    }
    return returnArr;
}


highlightMatch('Multi Test returns multiple results', 'multi'); 
=>  (5) ['<strong>Multi<strong>', 'Test', 'returns', '<strong>multi<strong>ple', 'results']
```