# Integrating custom function and rule using JQuery validator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form with an email field.
As part of the validation I would like to exclude certain domains ( eg gmail,yahoo etc )

I have found the following function which should search for substrings which I believe is a good choice to search my email strings in:
[jquery/javascript check string for multiple substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201939/jquery-javascript-check-string-for-multiple-substrings):

```
function isSubStringPresent(str){
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        if(str.indexOf(arguments[i]) > -1){
            return true;
        }
    }    
    return false;
}    

isSubStringPresent('myemail', 'gmail', 'yahoo', ...)
```

I am confused on how to integrate this function with the jquery validator plugin.

Please see below:

I have the following following below my form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.validator.addMethod(
                    "wrong_domain",
                    THE isSubStringPresent FUNCTION SHOULD BE INSERTED HERE SOMEHOW...                    
                    },
                    'Not an acceptable email' );

    $.validator.classRuleSettings.wrong_domain = { wrong_domain: true};    

$('#registration-form').validate({
        rules: {
           FirstName: {
            required: true,
          },

           Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            wrong_domain: true
          },
```

Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass in multiple excluded domains to the validation function:

```
var excludes = ['myemail', 'gmail', 'yahoo'];
$.validator.addMethod(
    "wrong_domain",
    function(value, element) { 
        // take a shallow copy of excludes
        var myArguments = excludes.slice(0);
        // add value to the front of the arguments
        myArguments.unshift(value);
        // use myArguments as the arguments array for isSubStringPresent
        return !isSubStringPresent.apply(this, myArguments);
    },
    'Not an acceptable email' );
```

Here's an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xc8E/3/). This will validate the input after every `keypress` event.