# js regex to find multiple substrings in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to find out if certain substrings exists in a string.

I have tried this:

```
x = "AAABBBCCC"
x.match(/(AAA|CCC)/)
```

However this resurns: `Array [ "AAA", "AAA" ]`

I would like to know exactly which substrings were present (e.g. `Array [ "AAA", "CCC" ]`)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now you have just one capture group with one value and it's returned if found.

If you add global flag to regex it returns all results

```
x.match(/(AAA|CCC)/g)
```

-> ["AAA", "CCC"]

Answer (score 2):

check for a global match, otherwise it will break when found the first

```
x = "AAABBBCCC"
x.match(/(AAA|CCC)/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the `g` global flag in your pattern. Like so:

```
x.match(/(AAA|CCC)/g);
```

This will return `["AAA", "CCC"]`. I really enjoy using [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) when figuring out expressions and as a documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var regEx = new RegExp('(AAA|CCC)','g');
var sample_string="AAABBBCCC";
var result = sample_string.match(regEx);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```