# Loop through Switch statement in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an object with key value pairs made of questions and answers. There are several different ways to ask the question,  so I'm trying to group questions that mean the same using a switch statement and the js match function.

```
{ 'Name?' : 'bob', q2: a2, .......}
```

I want to loop through the objects and find partial matches between the array elements and the object keys. So far I have:

```
switch (/terms/.test(key)) {

  case ( terms ="Name|What's Your Name?"):
    text = "matched";
    break;

  default:
    text = "default";
    Logger.log(key);

}

        Logger.log(text)




  });
```

The output in part shows:

```
18-10-09 15:37:41:415 EDT] *What's Your Name?* 
[18-10-09 15:37:41:416 EDT] default
```

Obviously a match is not occurring. How can I get this working?

EDIT:

I changed my code to:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {

switch (true) {

     case (/^Name|term2$/.test(key)):         
    text = "MATCHED!!!!";
    break;
  case 0:
  case 6:
    //        text = "It is Weekend";
    break;
  default:
    text = "default";
    Logger.log(key);

}

        Logger.log(text)


  });
```

Still no match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine switch cases like this:

```
switch (key) {
  case 'Name':
  case 'What\'s Your Name?':
    // Do something
    break;

  default:
    // Do something
}
```

This code is equivalent to:

```
if (key === 'Name' || key === 'What\'s Your Name?') {
  // Do something
} else {
 // Do something
}
```

Comment: What if I want to do it the basis of a partial match?

Comment: If I understand correctly , I could use .match to check for substrings of key (in case key is very long) --https://stackoverflow.com/a/15201998/1592380

Comment: @user61629 yes, you can, but you don't need to. The code in my answer should help you. You don't need to search for any substrings in your key.

Comment: You are right in this case so I will accept your answer (Thank you). but for a different situation, I'm still interested in knowing how to search for multiple substrings in a key.

Comment: @user61629 There are few options to do this but I'd recommend using Array.prototype.includes: `['term1', 'term2'].includes(string)` It will return true if string is equal to one of the terms in an array

Comment: How would I use this in the switch statement above?

Comment: @user61629 you should not use it in switch because it's a bad practice. But it's actually possible: `switch (true) { case (['term1', 'term2'].includes(string)): /* Do something */ break; }`

Comment: sorry , I'm using google apps script which is ECMA 5 based - I'm getting 'TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object ', I'm assuming because includes is not available..

Comment: I see. Than you can use regexp to search `/^term1|term2$/.test(string)`

Comment: I changed my code as in edit above but there is no match

Comment: @user61629 I see, the problem is that you are testing for `Name` while you have `Name?` in your key. So your regexp should be either `/^Name\?|term2$/` or `/Name|term2/`